# Error using httpd on CentOS

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, webserver, httpd, hostname

I am using CentOS. When I try to start httpd I receive the following error:

```
> sudo httpd

httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ccrhwp01948
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
```

Here is the hostname information:

```
> hostname

samp-serv3
```

There is no domain associated with this server. Simply an IP address. Here is the host information:

```
> nano /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain  localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Does anyone know how to properly fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: try issuing command "hostname samp-serv3"

Answer (score 0):

set FQDN hostname

```
echo HOST.DOMAIN.com > /etc/hostname
/bin/hostname -F /etc/hostname
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: Should I do samp-serv3.IPHERE? There is no specific domain associated with the IP.